# The effect of actions in one activity on another in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

In android studio I have two activities, **Main** and **Settings**.
The settings activity is called from main activity and there is a button for logging out. When I click on this button the settings activity finishes and the main activity appears again. How can I make the main activity know that the log out button was clicked?

And what if there is many actions that I can perform in settings activity?I don't want to return result to main activity, I want to write that actions somewhere and read from there in Main activity.

Comment: You mean if the user clicks on Logout then the app wants to close?

Comment: You could make use of the `onResume` method in the **Main** activity. In the method check if your user is still logged in.

Comment: can use `startActivtiyForResult()`

Comment: @Ali No I want to make the main activity know that the log out button was clicked?

Comment: Then you want to need follow -Ilham Bagoes Tripoetra Answer @VahagChakhoyan

Comment: @Ali I have edited question, please check.

Comment: @makuno I have edited question, please check.

Comment: @Priyankagb  I have edited question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

in mainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity .class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

than

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
      Intent data) {
      try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 123  && resultCode  == RESULT_OK) 
       {
            String requiredValue = data.getStringExtra("key");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, ex.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and set thus into your setting screen

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key", value);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

and check if value have data or anything you past that its come from setting screen

Comment: I didn't say I want to kill my app process.

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity you can start the SettingActivity using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingActivity .class);
startActivityForResult(intent, yourRequestCode);
```

after that in SettingActivity when you click the button logout, parse the boolean using

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.putExtra("isClicked", true); // save clicked data
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

then, in MainActivity you can call `onActivityResult` like this

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == yourRequestCode) {
        Boolean isLogoutClicked = data.getExtras().getBoolean("isClicked");
    }
```

now you get the data from the setting activity when the button logout is clicked.